# Threaded vs Event-based approach in async programming

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, event-driven

Going through literature, I understand applications can adopt two approaches for asynchronous programming:

- Launching a new thread for a time consuming task
- Event driven approach, which can be defined as(from book 'Learning Node')

> The second approach is to adopt an event-driven architecture. What happens is that
>   when a time-consuming process is invoked, the application doesn’t wait for it to finish.
>   Instead, the process signals when it’s finished by emitting an event. This event
>   gets added into a queue, or event loop. Any dependent functionality registers an interest
>   in this event with the application, and when the event is pulled from the event
>   loop and processed, the dependent functionality is invoked, with any event-related
>   data passed to it.

Popular argument against first approach is:

> The problem with this approach is
>   that threads are expensive. They’re expensive in resources, and they’re expensive in
>   added application complexity.

But I am not able to understand this argument. In event driven approach too threads would be needed to execute time consuming tasks. Isn't?

How does second approach scores over first one?

Edit: Node uses library [libuv](https://libuv.org/) to handle the threads for tasks.

Comment: this question has been asked many many times before in many different forms. google the term "asynchronous IO".

Comment: PS. libuv uses threads for blocking IO which doesn't have any asynchronous equivalent, like DNS lookup

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?